# Read Message From Alert and click on OK

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I want to read the message which is there in Alert.

Example: If a alert shows "Wrong E-mail address". How to read it? Means i want to store that message in a string.

How to click on OK inside Alert...??

How to do it using Selenium ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the Selenium WebDriver.

```
// Get a handle to the open alert, prompt or confirmation
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
// Get the text of the alert or prompt
alert.getText();  
// And acknowledge the alert (equivalent to clicking "OK")
alert.accept();
```

The answer was found [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_Does_WebDriver_support_Javascript_alerts_and_prompts?).

If you are using Selenium RC, take a look [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_Selenium_ISelenium_GetAlert.htm) webpage.

Comment: I updated my answer to include Selenium RC. Please check if it helps.

Comment: This is a better link, I think (to current trunk): http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_Selenium_ISelenium_GetAlert.htm

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Selenium RC if you know there's gonna be a confirmation button, then you **need** to add `selenium.getConfirmation();` to your code.

Here's how I've used it (**Note**: I'm using Java in Eclipse)

```
selenium.click("//input[@id=\"accepted-emails\"]"); // Confirmation box after this line
if (selenium.isConfirmationPresent())
    String confirmationString = selenium.getConfirmation(); // this line is needed
selenium.keyPressNative("10"); // to press the OK key
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
System.out.println(confirmationString); // this is not really needed, but used it to simply show the confirmation box message
```

Hope this helps!